# Write permission for folder on a remote server

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, permission-denied

I'm hosting a web site at localhost and need to upload image file to another server named ImageServer with the FileUploadControl.

```
if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
            FileUploadControl.SaveAs(@"\\ImageServer\" + filename);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

But i hit this permission error as soon as i try to submit an image.

> **Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\ImageServer\xxx.jpg' is denied.**
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request
>   identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically
>   {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6) that is used if
>   the application is not impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity will be
>   the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user. To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file
>   in Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click
>   "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET
>   account, and check the boxes for the desired access.

I looked into the folder security tab, and Network Service, IUSR, IIS AppPool\Image, and Everyone are granted full control. What else could be missing? I'm not sure what permission should i give to the image folder on ImageServer to let my localhost writing files to them.

P/S: Both server using IIS 7.5

Manually copy files to \\ImageServer\ via windows explorer works though

Comment: check write access on the folder for that user...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main trick is to create a virtual dir which points at \\ImageServer\.

I found an article [here](http://aspalliance.com/336_Upload_Files_Using_ASPNET_Impersonation_and_UNC_Share.all). Although is about IIS 6 I think it won't be a problem to work on IIS 7 also.